# Можно ли зарезервировать элементы (узлы) для std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли способ заставить `std::unordered_map` зарезервировать не только слоты (`buckets`), но и узлы?

Comment: так весь смысл эффективного использования хеш таблиц в том, чтобы узлов на каждый хеш было не более 1

Comment: что именно вкладывается в понятие «зарезервировать узлы»?  Может просто свой аллокатор сделать?

Comment: бери какую-нибуть кастомную реализацию мапы. unordered_map хорошо показывается в отладчике, но на этом её хорошие качества и заканчиваются.

Answer (score 2):

### Нет.

Резервирование служит для уменьшения количества реаллокаций. Работает для контейенров типа `vector`, когда при добалвении очередного элемента старые элементы перемещаются в бОльшую выделенную область. Оно является оптимизацией, позволяющей сразу выделить такую область.

Для `unordered_map` стандарт требует, чтобы при удалении любого элемента инвалидировались только итераторы и ссылки на него, но никакие другие итераторы и ссылки, и при добавлении тоже ничего не инвалидировалось. Соотвественно контейнер, которому резервирование помогло бы избежать реаллокацию, там нельзя всунуть: реаллокаций в любом случае не будет, ибо они запрещены.

По факту там (одно или дву)связный список в каждой корзине. При этом, оптимистично ожидается, что в корзине обычно не более одного элемента, для этого корзин сильно больше, чем нужно, и многие пустуют. Соотвественно, попытки предвыделять узлы, или иметь более одного элемента в узле были бы пессимизацией.

Вообще задачу оптимизации выделения `unordered_map` решить можно либо своим аллокатором, либо отказом от `unordered_map` (в пользу других типов хеш-таблиц, например)

Comment: Из всего этого никак не следует того, что невозможно всунуть аллокацию памяти для конечных узлов заранее. То, что нельзя передвинуть элементы, никак не означает того, что нельзя заранее выделить под новые память.

Comment: Да, но из всего этого следует, что оно было бы бесполезно, и даже вредно

Comment: Это не бесполезно. Например для использования unordered map внутри глобального оператора new.

И не вижу ничего вредного в том, чтобы использовать pool аллокатор для unordered map.

Comment: Резервировать заранее узлы таки бесполезно, потому что  заранее неизвестно, в каких корзинах узлы.

Comment: Резервировать узлы вне корзин для того, чтобы не выделять память в определённый момент -- можно было бы, но это не делается. Избегание аллокаций в определённый момент не является целью reserve, это лишь сторонний эффект, цель же производительость, которой резервирование узлов не способстует

Comment: И каким же образом pool аллокатор не способствует производирельности?

Comment: Пул аллокатор ортогонален резервированию. Резервирование, если бы оно было, не способствовало производительности. Про использование не-дефолтного аллокатора в своём ответе я, напротив, отметил, что это может быть полезно.